# Why doesn't the .at function work for pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function

I have the following code in which I access a CSV file with multiple columns containing numbers and want to change a specific column under certain conditions, with the .at function within pandas, which does not work for some reason:

```
import csv

import pandas



final_activities = pandas.read_csv("VPN2/VPN2_Final_Activities.csv", delimiter=';', names=['Timerels', 'ActivityClass_Ankle', 'ActivityClass_Hip', 'ActivityClass_Thigh', 'ActivityClass_Wrist', 'ActivityClass_Annotation'], skip_blank_lines=True, skipinitialspace=True, engine='python', header=0)



i = 0

while i < len(final_activities):

  ankle_activity = final_activities.loc[i][1]

  annotation_activity = final_activities.loc[i][5]

  if(int(annotation_activity) == 9 and int(ankle_activity) == 2):

    final_activities.at[i, 'ActivityClass_Ankle'] = 9

  i += 1
```

In this case, nothing is being modified in the final_activities DataFrame due to the .at statement. It used to work for me before.

Comment: `final_activities.loc[i][1]` is making a copy of the DataFrame, which is what you are updating, not the original. Use `final_activities.loc[i, 1]`